# Simplifying selectionsort and mergesort

Tags: sorting, haskell, implementation, mergesort, simplify

I have managed to implement insertionsort and quicksort in a couple of lines, but selectionsort and mergesort still give me headaches ;)

```
selectionsort [] = []

selectionsort (x:xs) =
    let (minimum, greater) = extractMinimum x [] xs
    in  minimum : selectionsort greater

extractMinimum minimumSoFar greater [] = (minimumSoFar, greater)

extractMinimum minimumSoFar greater (x:xs)
    | x < minimumSoFar = extractMinimum x (minimumSoFar:greater) xs
    | otherwise        = extractMinimum minimumSoFar (x:greater) xs
```

Is something like the `extractMinimum` function available in the standard library? I tried hoogling for `(a -> a -> Bool/Ordering) -> [a] -> (a, [a])` without any luck.

```
mergesort [ ] = [ ]

mergesort [x] = [x]

mergesort xs =
    let (left, right) = splitAt (length xs `div` 2) xs
    in  merge (mergesort left) (mergesort right)

merge xs [] = xs

merge [] ys = ys

merge xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys)
    | x < y     = x : merge  xs yys
    | otherwise = y : merge xxs  ys
```

Again, do I have to write `merge` myself, or can I reuse existing components? Hoogle gave me no useful results for `(a -> a -> Bool/Ordering) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: n.b. @sudo_o and whoever approved that edit: [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is a search engine that allows you to search for Haskell library functions by type signature; it is not a typo of Google.

Comment: By the way, top-down mergesort is a very poor idea with lists in Haskell. You spend a bunch of time splitting lists and finding the length of lists. Working from the bottom up is much simpler. Start by converting the input to length-one lists, then merge adjacent pairs of lists until there's only one left.

Comment: @Carl What if I compute the length of the list only once at the beginning and then pass the smaller lengths down explicitly?

Comment: @FredOverflow It won't remove the cost of repeated `splitAt`s.  That's an O(n) operation on immutable lists.

Comment: Should it be moved to codereview?

Comment: @Carl How about [this one](http://ideone.com/Ubia8)? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the standard libraries, but at least [`merge`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-ordlist/0.4.5/doc/html/Data-List-Ordered.html#v%3amerge) is provided by a package on [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org), although I'm not sure it's worth pulling in a dependency for such a simple function.

However,

```
merge xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys)
    | x < y     = x : merge  xs yys
    | otherwise = y : merge xxs  ys
```

produces a non-stable sort, to get a stable sort, the condition to place `x` should be `x <= y`.

For `extractMinimum`, I haven't found anything either, but I can offer an alternative definition,

```
extractMinimum :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> (a,[a])
extractMinimum x = foldl' select (x, [])
  where
    select (mini, greater) y
      | y < mini  = (y, mini:greater)
      | otherwise = (mini, y:greater)
```

A nice definition of `selectionSort` would be

```
import Data.List -- for unfoldr

selectionSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
selectionSort = unfoldr getMin
  where
    getMin [] = Nothing
    getMin (x:xs) = Just $ extractMinimum x xs
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for selection sort:

```
import Data.List

selectionsort xs = unfoldr f xs where
    f [] = Nothing
    f xs = Just $ extractMinimum xs

extractMinimum (x:xs) = foldl' f (x,[]) xs where
  f (minimum, greater) x | x < minimum = (x, minimum : greater)
                         | otherwise = (minimum, x : greater)
```